Zustand updates the state but not the React component
I want to use Zustand as a state management library in my react webapp. Unfortunately, with my current implementation, the UI does not update automatically after the state is changed.
I have to use setState and getState to manipulate the state, otherwise I get an error, see Invalid hook call - Zustand in React (Typscript) using Inversify
How do I have to adapt the code so that changes are automatically registered by the UI?
service.ts
@injectable()
export class Service {
  private store = useInjection(Store);

  public async run() {
    this.restaurantStore.test.setState({ paw: false });
    this.restaurantStore.test.getState().increment();
  }
}


store.ts
export interface Test {
  paw: boolean;
  count: number;
  increment: () => void;
}

type NamedSetState<T extends State> = (
  partial: PartialState<T>,
  name?: any,
) => void;

@injectable()
export class Store {
  public test = create(
    devtools(
      immer((set: NamedSetState<Test>) => ({
        paw: true,
        count: 0,
        increment: () => {
          console.debug("Test.");
          set((state) => ({
            count: state.count + 1,
          }));
        },
      })),
    ),
  );
}

dropdown.tsx
export const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const service = useInjection(Service);
  const store = useInjection(Store);

  const {count, paw} = store.test();

  const data = {
    test: [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c",
    ],
  };

  const onInputChange = async () => {
    await service.run()
  };

  return (
    <>
      {count}
      {String(paw)}
      <Autocomplete
        size="md"
        options={data.test}
        onInputChange={(event, value) => onInputChange(value)}
      />
    </>
  );
};

